# How to set the GeometryReader's frame height

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swiftui

I'd like to dynamically set the frame height of PagerViewTest without manually set the height  acting directly on the GeometryReader ( see the commented out line).
As you can see in the picture the frame has a size much bigger than the circle. I'd like it to be just as big as the circle.

[image]

```html
struct PagerViewTest<Content: View>: View {
  let content: Content

  init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
  }

  var body: some View {

    GeometryReader { geometry in
      HStack(spacing: 0) {
        return content
          .frame( alignment: .leading)
      }
    }
    //    .frame(height: 200) // TODO: should not be hardcoded!
  }

}

struct PagerViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    PagerViewTest() {
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 200)
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 200)
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 200)
    }
    .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
  }
}
```

Comment: you should give a frame or size to your circle! right? then give that frame or size to GeometryReader

Answer (score 0):

Circle is a Shape - it does not have own size. So we need to give it a frame that should be filled. As soon as we did it, there will be no needs in GeometryReader in page view.

Here is updated code. Tested with Xcode 12.1 / iOS 14.1

*Note: GeometryReader does not care about internal content, it consumes available space in outer container and provide it to inner one.*

[image: demo]

```
struct PagerViewTest<Content: View>: View {
  let content: Content

  init(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = content()
  }

  var body: some View {
      HStack(spacing: 0) {
        return content
          .frame( alignment: .leading)
      }
  }

}

struct PagerViewTest_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    PagerViewTest() {
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
      Circle()
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
    .previewLayout(.sizeThatFits)
  }
}
```